# How can I send duplicate packets, one instantly and one with a delay?

Tags: linux, networking

For testing on Linux, I can create duplicate packets where both are sent instantly with the following command:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev IFACE root netem duplicate 100%
```

How can I create duplicate packets where one is sent instantly and the other is sent with a configurable delay? Using `tc` isn't a requirement.